# how to store a trained classifier on an open source app?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I used Python's scikit-learn package to train an SVM classifier (an instance of `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier()`). Now I'm using this trained classifier in an open source web app I'm developing. The idea is simple: user inputs "foo" and the classifier responds with "hi, 'foo' belongs to class 'bar'".

On my local machine I'm storing the trained classifier in a pickle file, which is loaded every time I serve the app. Simple enough. But for security reasons people aren't supposed to open pickle files they haven't create themselves. Also, I've read somewhere that one shouldn't pickle.dump and pickle.load scikit-learn objects using different scikit-learn versions.

So, how do I open source this? Do I just put the pickle file up for download, together with the code, and hope people trust it and use the right scikit-learn version? Somehow that sounds wrong - I've never cloned a repository that had pickle files. There must be another way. How do people usually go about it? Also, not sure if it's relevant, but the pickle is pretty large (8GB).